# Least squared method confusion with matrices

Tags: matrices, statistics, regression, least-squares

I have a little problem with my homework in a subject called "Matrices in statistics".

The task is as follows:

Find  $\Big( \begin{matrix} a \\ b  \end{matrix} \Big)$
least squared estimations by $x_i$ and $y_i$.

What I've tried to do so far, is ..

$\Big( \begin{matrix} \widehat{a} \\ \widehat{b}  \end{matrix} \Big) = (K^{T}K)^{-1}K^{T} \vec{y} = 
$$ \left[\Big( \begin{matrix} x_{1} .... x_{n} \\ 1 ...... 1  \end{matrix} \Big)
 \Bigg(\begin{matrix} x_{1} \quad 1 \\ ...  \\ x_{n} \quad 1  \end{matrix} \Bigg) 
 \right]^{-1}  \Big( \begin{matrix} x_{1} .... x_{n} \\ 1 ...... 1  \end{matrix} \Big)     \Bigg(\begin{matrix} y_{1}  \\ ...  \\ y_{n}   \end{matrix} \Bigg) = 
 \left[\begin{matrix}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}  \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n}  x_{i}\\ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \qquad n   \end{matrix}  \right]  
\Bigg(\begin{matrix}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}y_{i}  \\  \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}    \end{matrix} \Bigg) $

..

I think I've done correctly thus far, but I don't know how to continue from there. I would be very thankful if you could help me!

Comment: You are missing an inverse on the last matrix. You have given the formula for the coefficients so I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking whether how to progress from this point ..

Comment: Have you been given a data set, if so, then plug in the numbers.

Comment: No, I haven't. The task is purely theoretic.

Comment: Then I would presume you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\hat{\beta} = (\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta} ) ^T$. Note that 
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty,
$$
where 
\begin{align}
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 \\
: & :\\
1 & x_n \\
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
hence, 
\begin{align}
X'X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \sum x_i \\
\sum x_i  & \sum x_i ^2\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
As such, 
\begin{align}
(X'X)^{-1} = 
(n \sum (x _i - \bar{x})^2)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum x_i ^2 & - \sum x_i \\
- \sum x_i  & n\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{y} - \hat{\beta} \bar{x} \\
\frac{\sum ( x_i - \bar{x} ) (y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}